# it is possible to have popup notification in communities as we have with lightning sales license?

Tags: lightning-community, event, notification

I have a lightning community for promotors and they set reminders for the events, but they dont see the reminders because the warning doesnt appear as a sales licence.    Picture related it is possible to have those reminders in communities?

[image: I want to have this reminders in lightning community users]

Comment: you can code notifications/popups in a custom component that can be used in communities

Comment: thanks, do you have an example?

Comment: there are plenty of documented samples online - I would suggest you take a look at it and try to do so by yourself. If you encounter any issues, feel free to open a new post. Thanks